# Sum of Integer Numbers in a txt File

Tags: python, string, text, indexing, int

I have two txt files that contain only numbers (number per line), so I want to add line 1 + line 1 so in succession to the last line of each file. Each file has the same line number.

**I'm trying this way, however I can only print the first line**

```
arq = open ("List1.txt")
arq2 = open ("List2.txt")

x = [linha.strip() for linha in arq]
arq.close()
y = [linha.strip() for linha in arq2]
arq2.close()

for linha in x:
    index = 0
    while index<len(x):
       result = (int(x[index]) + int(y[index]))
       index += 1
    print result
```

Comment: See if you can make use of [zip()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#zip).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve this easily using `zip`.

Change the relevant lines of code to:

```
for x, y in zip(arq, arq2):
    result = int(x) + int(y)
    print(result)
```

Comment: @MrT He has mentioned in the question that both the files have same length

Comment: yes, both files have the same amount of rows so there are no problems. Thanks for the answer. @nisemonoxide

Comment: Sure thing. (y)

Answer (score 1):

While you should probably use `zip` like mentioned above, if you want to keep on using your way of doing things your problem is here

when you `for` loop in python, it's a foreach, so when you do

```
for linha in x:
    print linha
```

`linha` will be the value of `x[n]` where n is the iteration of the loop

anyways, to fix your code you'd do

```
# no need for the for loop, pull everything back
index = 0
while index< min(len(x), len(y)): # make sure you check for both lengths in case they are not the same
    result = (int(x[index]) + int(y[index]))
    index += 1
    print result # you want to print the result inside the loop so you don't lose it on the next iteration
```

the proper way to do it though would be

```
for n,p in zip(x,y):
    print int(n) + int(p)
```

Answer (score 0):

First I would get a numpy array and concatenate

```
import numpy as np
file1 = np.genfromtxt('file1')
file2 = np.genfromtxt('file2')
file3 = np.concatenate((file1, file2), axis=1)
```

then save however you see fit